# Make Rails generate single quote strings rather than double quote strings to satisfy RuboCop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, rubocop

How can I make Rails generate single quoted strings rather than double quoted strings when it generates code, such as migrations?

I'm not too fussed about what kind of strings are used in migrations, but it causes complications for RuboCop. The only way I can envisage RuboCop ignoring it is if I explicitly tell it to ignore the offending files, or to not enforce the Style/StringLiterals cop at all.

Comment: yeah, this tends to prove the debate doesnt worth it: http://viget.com/extend/just-use-double-quoted-ruby-strings

Comment: @apneadiving The creator of RuboCop commented in that thread, FWIW: http://viget.com/extend/just-use-double-quoted-ruby-strings#comment-1810997001

Comment: well, as you feel :)

Comment: The thread has suffered the fate of linkrot, comments are gone :(

Answer (score 6):

I think you shouldn't be checking style in autogenerated files, as you are not really writing them. I would exclude files such as `db/data_schema.rb` in your `rubocop.yml` file.

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/schema.rb'
```

The files in `db/migrate/` are not really autogenerated as you also can write your own migrations. You could exclude `Style/StringLiterals` only for migrations in your `rubocop.yml` file:

```
Style/StringLiterals:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/migrate/*'
```

You can also run rubocop auto-correction after generating the migration, as Rubocop can efficiently correct Style/StringLiterals offenses:

```
rubocop -a
```